# I have two tables departments and employees and I want to get department name where employee skill is not equal to programmer but it's not working

Tags: sql

```
select distinct Departments.DEPT_NAME 
from Employees,Departments 
where Departments.DEPT_ID=Employees.DEPT_ID and emp_skill <>'Programmer';
```

I used another query and it works fine but  I want to what is the error in this

Comment: Please provide a sample of both tables, the output from this current query, and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT D.DEPT_NAME 
FROM Departments D
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Employees E WHERE E.DEPT_ID = D.DEPT_ID AND E.emp_skill <> 'Programmer');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use not exists

```
SELECT a.DEPT_NAME 
FROM Departments a
WHERE not EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Employees b WHERE b.DEPT_ID = a.DEPT_ID
                               AND E.emp_skill = 'Programmer'
                   );
```